# Ethernet II frames with src mac addr 00:01:02:03:04:05 after connecting to home wifi router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ethernet, traffic, network-traffic

I'm curious about this and haven't been able to find any satisfactory answer to my question (possibly because I don't know exactly what to look for here).

When I connect to my home network, I see a lot of (around 600 or more) Ethernet II frames just like in this picture:
[Wireshark capture printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTq9o.png)

And I just can't figure out what it is.

If I have a look into the data, I can see things like ssdp and upnp, which are both protocols, but here I only see there frames, no other ssdp or upnp traffic. Dst mac addr is always my interface, there are none frames in the other direction.

So my broad question is where to look to find out more. What are these frames?

Thank you

**EDIT:** this happens no matter how many devices are connected in my network, could be 2 or more or even 1

Comment: Have you simply plugged the MAC into a search engine?

Comment: Guess someone was too lazy to actually do unique addresses. Disconnect devices from your network until you find the culprit.

Comment: It happens even when I have only one device connected to my wifi. So it's my router and one device and I see this traffic.

Comment: So it’s probably your router then. Is it ISP-provided? Are you sure your computer isn’t looking for UPnP devices before (uses multicast, so you won’t see them unless you change your filter)?

Comment: Yes, I have a ISP-provided router. My best guess is it is the router, although when I ping it (the default gateway), the response comes from a different MAC addr, so I don't understand this 00:01:02:03:04:05 MAC addr. As for the second question, I'm not sure, I'll have a closer look today again.

Comment: So I've done a little bit of digging and reading. And I think I'm one step closed to the answer. I actually think this is SSDP traffic from my router that only this machine (or sth) cannot display properly as SSDP traffic and so it shows only like Ethernet II frames. I've tried to capture traffic on a different machine and I can see the same values as in the uploaded picture,  but as SSDP traffic. So that's probably the end of this topic, another question would be why Wireshark doesn't display it as SSDP traffic, but it'd be OT here. So unless I'm really wrong here, I consider this closed.